# How to associate two different post types (think Book and Chapter)

Tags: custom-post-types

I just recently started learning Custom Post Types, but haven't been able to find any documentation that would allow me (at least in the admin) to nest them.

My requirements are, a book post type with cover image (feature image) and description/summary (editor), and a chapter post type with chapter image (featured image), editor, excerpt

Both of these are easy, and really quick to accomplish, only hard part is I need them nested, so when you click into a book in the admin, you can see/edit the details, and add a chapter from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Posts 2 Posts plugin](http://scribu.net/wordpress/posts-to-posts).

Comment: Unfortunately unless this is automatic, it wont work for the task at hand.

Comment: It is not automatic. But it offers a good api that you can use as starting pont: http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/posts-to-posts/tags/0.4/api.php.